# Nested GridView with RadioButtonList Control in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gridview

I have 2 GridViews nested one in another with radio button list controls. The first Grid view's Radio Button list have list items like Yes, No, N/A. When the "No" List item is clicked it should show the nested grid view and its associated radio buttons.

I can see all the grid views and its associated radiobuttons when the page is loaded but the gridview2 doesnot show and hide when the "no" radiobutton is clicked. I used javascript for that functionality but not working as desired. I am providing my vb.net code and aspx code. Any help is appreciated.

**Vb.net Code**

Public Class _Default

```
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        GridView1.DataSource = GetData("select * from Questions")

        GridView1.DataBind()


    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("String").ConnectionString

    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = query

            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()

                cmd.Connection = con

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd

                Using ds As New DataSet()

                    Dim dt As New DataTable()

                    sda.Fill(dt)

                    Return dt

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using

    End Using

End Function



Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim questid As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString()

        Dim GridView2 As GridView = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("GridView2"), GridView)

        GridView2.DataSource = GetData(String.Format("SELECT * from Standards where Questions= '{0}'", questid))

        GridView2.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

**Aspx Page**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CssClass="Grid"
 DataKeyNames="QstnID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Questions" />  
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="QuestList" runat="server" DataValueField="Question" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
              <asp:ListItem Enabled="False" Style="display: none" Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="N/A">N/A</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br> 
       </br>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Standards" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StandList" runat="server" DataValueField="Description" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="False" Style="display: none" Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Selected="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="N/A">N/A</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br>
        </br>

    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Response" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:String1%>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Description] FROM [Standards]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="WcmQC" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:String2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Question] FROM [Questions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#QuestList input').click(function () {
            var value = $('#QuestList input:checked').val();
            if (value == "Yes") {
                $("#GridView2").show();
             else {
                 $("#GridView2").hide();  
            }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you're using the id "QuestList":

`$('#QuestList input').click(function () {`

Since it's a server control, it will have a client id made up of "QuestList" preceded by a hierarchy of container names. And it's also within a repeater/grid, which complicates its id further.

Instead of id, use class to target your list. Something like this:

`<asp:RadioButtonList ID="QuestList" CssClass="MyListClass" runat="server" DataValueField="Question" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">`

and

`$('.MyListClass input').click(function () {`

Comment: It is not working. I tried the parent and child grids css class but still not working.

Comment: It should be closer to working than before. Try to find out more about what's happening, by debugging the javascript, and also by adding temporary javascript to display an alert at different points to show which code is being hit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and found several JS errors, which were stopping the event-handling from working. I have shown some fixes in the code sample below, which are:

1. Where you pull in the JQuery script, you need to close the line with  `</script>`. You can't merge it with a general script block as you've tried to do.
2. Referring to my first answer (on the subject of client and server ids), you need to fix your id for #GridView2 as well. In this case I would possibly use a server script block to get the client id (more on this below).
3. You have mismatching braces in your `if` statement. You don't need the brace on the first line, but if you prefer that style and do include it, you are missing the matching one before the `else`:

   `if (value == "Yes") {
      $("#GridView2").show();
    else`
4. Whereas I suggested using class rather than id to attach your click handler, don't do the same within the handler to target the radiobutton that was clicked. There are multiple radiobuttons of that class. Instead, use `this` to target the event source object (the radiobutton that was clicked).

Copied below for you is the working JS I ended up with after applying the above fixes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.MyListClass input').click(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
<%--     if (this.value == "Yes") 
            $("#GridView2").show();
         else 
            $("#GridView2").hide();  --%>
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, it only shows an alert at present, because I'm afraid you still have some investigation and design to do, to decide how to target the right instance of GridView2 in your event handler. However, this will easy enough, there's more than one approach and with a bit of patience you should now be able to work it out from the other info I've given plus some googling. HTH.